# Access Violation when handling forms

Tags: delphi

I have procedure to show/hide one element on TForm like that:

```
procedure ShowHideControl(const ParentForm: TForm; const ControlName: String; ShowControl: Boolean);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to pred(ParentForm.ComponentCount) do
  begin
    if (ParentForm.Components[i].Name = ControlName) then
    begin
      if ShowControl then
        TControl(ParentForm.Components[i]).Show
      else
        TControl(ParentForm.Components[i]).Hide;

      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

then I try to use it like:

```
procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowHideEveryControl(TForm(TForm1), 'Button4', True);
end;
```

Why do I get Access Violation on Button6 click?

For me everything is OK... Button4 exists as a child :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cast is wrong:

```
TForm(TForm1)
```

You are telling the compiler to ignore the fact that `TForm1` is not a `TForm` instance, and asking it to pretend that it is. That is fine until you actually try to use it as an instance, and then the error occurs.

You need to pass a real instance to a `TForm` descendent. You can write it like this:

```
ShowHideEveryThing(Self, 'Button4', True);
```

Just in case you are not clear on this, the parameter of your procedure is of type `TForm`. That means you need to supply an **instance** of a class that either is, or derives from `TForm`. I repeat, you must supply an instance. But you supply `TForm1` which is a **class**.

---

And then the next problem comes here:

```
if (ParentForm.Components[i].Name = FormName) then
begin
  if ShowForm then
    TForm(ParentForm.Components[i]).Show
  else
    TForm(ParentForm.Components[i]).Hide;

  Break;
end;
```

Again you have used an erroneous cast. When the compiler tells you that it a particular object does not have a method, you must listen to it. It's no good telling the compiler to shut up and pretend that an object of one type is really an object of a different type. Your button is categorically not a form, so don't try to cast it to `TForm`.

It is very hard to know what you are actually trying to do here. When you write:

```
ShowHideEveryThing(Self, 'Button4', True);
```

It would seem to me to me more sensible to write:

```
Button4.Show;
```

It is not a good idea to refer to controls using their names represented as text. It is much safer and cleaner to refer to them using reference variables. That way you let the compiler do its job and check the type safety of your program.

---

The names used in your function are suspect:

```
procedure ShowHideEveryThing(const ParentForm: TForm; const FormName: String; 
  ShowForm: Boolean);
```

Let's look at them:

- `ShowHideEveryThing`: but you claim that the function should show/hide one element. That does not tally with the use of *everything*.
- `FormName`: you actually pass a component name, and then look for components owned by `ParentForm` that have that name. It seems that `FormName` is wrong.
- `ShowForm`: again, do you want to control visibility of the form, or a single element?

Clearly you need to step back and be clear on the intent of this function.

---

As an aside, you should generally never need to write:

```
if b then
  Control.Show
else
  Control.Hide;
```

Instead you can write:

```
Control.Visible := b;
```

---

My number one piece of advice to you though is to stop casting until you understand it properly. Once you understand it properly, design your code if at all possible so that you don't need to cast. If you ever really do need to cast, make sure that your cast is valid, ideally by using a checked cast with the `as` operator. Or at least testing first with the `is` operator.

Your code shows all the hallmarks of a classic mistake. The compiler objects to the code that you write. You have learnt from somewhere that casting can be used to suppress these compiler errors and now you apply this technique widely as a means to make your program compile. The problem is that the compiler invariably knows what it is talking about. When it objects, listen to it. If ever you find yourself suppressing a compiler error with a cast, take a step back and think carefully about what you are doing. The compiler is your friend.

Comment: the solution is working, thanks...
I did cast like: 

TControl(ParentForm.Components[i]).Visible

Should it work for every visual component?

Comment: @user3243859 The fact that you have to cast to make it compile tells you that it will not work for every component. It works provided that the components are derived from `TControl`. You do need to check that.

Comment: Might I ask why you rejected simply writing `Button4.Show` in `Button6Click`? I've done a lot of GUI development and never once referred to control by their name. It feels like you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm working on the general procedure solution... it's just example with the Button4 to hide it :)

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use names to identify your controls? I mean, perhaps there is a good reason, but if you can avoid it you should. Perhaps you don't know how to avoid it, or don't realise the benefits of avoiding having to specify controls by name.

Comment: I there a better solution to find and recognize components on TForm?

Comment: Why do you need to search for them? Don't you already know what's there since you wrote the code and designed the forms? I'm trying to understand your underlying problem.

Comment: I can delete every item that begins with "Butt..." name :-)

Comment: Fair enough. Why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: If I build library... I can say to the end-user to put 3 custom-edit pre-prepared controls on the form and name it as I want... to give the end-user kind of proper interface (Control is showing few variables and have let's say TrackBar :). I know it's better to give for example pre-prepared TForm on procedure but it's only academic talking ... Have you got any better ideas?

Comment: I don't really understand. But never mind, it sounds like you are doing something more dynamic than typical UI dev. But remember my advice about casting!